# C# typedef generics

Tags: c#, generics, typedef

I am using a shorthand version for a class, which looks like this:

```
using NodeSteps = Tuple<Node, int>;
```

Node is a class defined by myself. This works fine usually, but the problem here is, is that Node is a generic requiring a struct.

My questions are as follows:

1.
How are these typedefs called in C#. I know they are not exactly typedefs, but it was the most similar thing I could think of.

2.
How can I make a generic version?

```
using NodeSteps<T> = Tuple<Node<T>, int>;
```

I noticed this is not the way to do it. I also would like to specify T is a struct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. They are called aliases.
2. No, this isn't possible. C# Language spec:

> Using aliases can name a closed constructed type, but cannot name an unbound generic type declaration without supplying type arguments.

Therefore, `using x<T> = List<T>` or something similar isn't possible.

You may use a class (see the other answers(s)) instead.

Answer (score 9):

Use

```
class NodeSteps<T> : Tuple<Node<T>, int>
{
}
```

This is the closest equivalent to a typedef I know of. If there are any non-default constructors, you would need to declare them, though.

Answer (score 6):

This is covered in section 9.4.1 of the C# Language spec.

> Using aliases can name a closed constructed type, but cannot name an
>   unbound generic type declaration without supplying type arguments.

This is called alias and can not be generic, but **right hand** of the using can be generic

```
using ListOfInts = List<int>
```

is valid

Answer (score 3):

```
using NodeSteps = Tuple<Node, int>;
```

is not the equivalent of a `typdef` but just an *alias* to that class.  It's designed to work around namespace collisions without having to use the whole namespace.  What I would do is define a new class:

```
public class NodeSteps<T> : Tuple<Node<T>, int> where t: struct
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
namespace Test1
{
    class Node<T>
    {
        public T Test()
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}

namespace Test1
{
    using NodeSteps = System.Tuple<Node<string>, int>;

    public class Class1
    {
         public static void Main()
         {
            NodeSteps t1 = new NodeSteps(new Node<string>(), 10);

            t1.Item1.Test();
         }
    }
}
```