# How can you statically bind types together (as in TypeToType<T>) in C# using generics?

Tags: c#, c++, generics, metaprogramming, type-safety

Say I have a suite of types of the form `BooleanAttribute`, `ContinuousAttribute`, `FiveStarAttribute`, etc. Each of these is conceptually bound to a value type (e.g. `bool`, `double`, `int` for the examples above.) Each also inherits from a common base class `AttributeBase`.

Say I have another generic class called `AttributeUpgrade<Attr>` that contains as a member an instance of `Attr`, where `Attr` inherits from `AttributeBase`. I would also like it to contain two instances (old and new) of the value type conceptually bound to `Attr`.

With C++ templates, this would be trivial. In each type in the Attribute suite I would define a typedef for ValueType, and declare my members as

```
template <typename Attr>
class AttributeUpgrade
{
    Attr attribute;

    typename Attr::ValueType old; 
    typename Attr::ValueType new;
...
```

So far the equivalent solution in C#, or anything near it, has alluded me. Any solutions would be appreciated, even if they involve tearing apart some of the structure in the example. As it stands, I am headed towards dropping type-safety and just typing old and new as objects. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class AttributeUpgrade<T> where T : Attr
{
    T oldOne; 
    T newOne;
}
```

And be aware that `new` is a reserved keyword.

The where clause is optional but you might want to restrict the used types to `Attr`

**Edit:** I have omitted access specifiers on class and on members for the sake of clarity as I am not aware of what access level is needed.

**Edit:** Answer from comments:

In my words: You wish to re-use the template parameter from Attr in the declaration of AttributeUpgrade without introducing a new generic parameter to AttributeUpdate.

This cannot be done in C#.

You will either need the second template parameter or resort to the use of `GetType()` on the Attr's inner type to get a `System.Type` (but as you are aware of this, there is no type safety here). 
C++ solves this by using typedefs in classes. The closest thing here are aliases but they cannot provide the feature you need.

See stackoverflow.com/questions/19790556/c-sharp-typedef-generics .

Indeed I think that the "best" way here would be to add another template parameter and runtime(!) assert that Attr's inner type is equal the one's in `AttributeUpgrade`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately then I would have no way of getting back to Attr. I could of course define AttributeUpgrade with two generic parameters, but since they are intrinsically linked I would like to avoid going down that road. As a terrible example, I would like to define Equipment<Elephant> instead of Equipment<ElephantSnack, ElephantSaddle, HowToTrainYourElephantBluRay>. The latter types are all implied by the former, just as T in your example is implied by Attr.

Comment: Please elaborate how you want to get back to Attr from your class? You can use the members in my sample class (make them more accessible, properties or getters of some sort).

Comment: In your example you declared oldOne and newOne as type T, where T inherits from Attr. Instead I would like to declare three members: two of type T (which could inherit from a base class like AttributeValueType) and one of type Attr, where Attr and T are both generic params. The trick is that Attr and T are mapped one-to-one! For Attr = BooleanAttribute I will always have T = bool (or some wrapper type.) Similarly for Attr = ContinuousAttribute, T will always be float. As you can see I'd like to avoid writing AttributeUpgrade<ContinuousAttribute, float> because it is duplicating information!

Comment: Either I really don't understand what you are doing or you are off the road. If Attr takes NO generic parameter, then feel free to add a Attr param to my sample above. If however Attr is itself an Attr<T> you will need to pass this param redundantly to AttributeUpgrade in order to be able to create am member of Attr<T> in your class. Is this your issue?

Comment: @user2555938 I think I now got what you want. Let me check the docs whether this is possible in C#

Comment: I think we're almost on the same page (thanks again!) I could add Attr as a second generic parameter, yes. But conceptually there is only one thing that varies, not two. To make another dumb example, I wouldn't want a class AnimalDrawing<AnimalHead, AnimalBody> because then to use it I must write nasty things like AnimalDrawing<ZebraHead, ZebraBody>. Really what I want is AnimalDrawing<Zebra>. In fact, the former opens the door to erroneous combinations like AnimalDrawing<ZebraHead, DuckBody>. Such it is with T and Attr, because Attr implies T.

Comment: @user2555938 Unfortunately you will either need the second argument or resort of using of GetType() on the Attr's inner type to get a System.Type (but as you are aware of this, there is no type safety here). C++ solves this by using typedefs in classes. The closes thing here are aliases but they cannot provide the feature you need. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790556/c-sharp-typedef-generics . Indeed I think that the "best" way here would be to add another template parameter and runtime(!) assert that Attr's inner type is equal the one's in AttributeUpgrade.

Comment: Excellent summary, that's as I feared. Thank you again for investigating. If you update the answer with that last comment I will happily accept it!

Comment: What he's asking for can't be done in C++ either.  He needs a single T that binds the operations together.  Like `interface IAnimalDrawer { void DrawHead(); void DrawBody(); }`.  Now T can be `class Zebra : IAnimalDrawer { ... }`.

Comment: @user2555938 Updated my answer to include link and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to write C++ templates using C# generics. However, they are a bit different in concept as well as in execution. What are you actually trying to create? What's the original problem you're solving?

If I understand your intent, the simple solution is to have AttributeBase itself be generic.

```
class AttributeBase<T>
{
    T value;
}

class BooleanAttribute: AttributeBase<bool>
{

}

class AttributeUpgrade<T> 
{
    AttributeBase<T> attribute;

    T oldValue;
    T newValue;
}

// Or alternatively...
class AttributeUpgrade<T, K>
    where T : AttributeBase<K>
{
    T attribute;

    K oldValue;
    K newValue;
}
```

If you can't afford to use a generic base class, you can use interfaces to redefine some things as needed (ie. either have a generic template and a non-generic class or vice versa), but I expect that is not the case, since you would have the same problem with C++ templates.

Unlike templates, C# generics are resolved on demand in runtime, they're not simply a pre-processor step during compilation. This of course has its pros and cons, and they're not the same thing at all. This doesn't mean you can't use generics to solve a problem you solved with templates in C++ - but it's not just syntactic sugar like in C++. You could use code generators to do something like C++ templates do, but that's beyond the scope of an SO question :D

Comment: Just a note, there is no such thing as generics in C++, I think you mean templates (and there are considerable differences!) :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice There *wasn't* such thing as generics in C++. However, in C++/CLI (the C++ on .NET), there are the same generics as in C#, as well as C++ templates. And now C++11 added generics... which again, is something completely different. Good luck understanding all that :D But yeah, as you correctly pointed out, I used *generics* instead of *templates* in my answer in that one sentence right at the top :D

Comment: ,weelllll ;)  C++11 generics is really a macro-expander that expands based on the type (you'd not use it on class declarations for example), and whilst you're right about C++/CLI, I think only 3 people use it and the OP isn't one :P

Comment: @Moo-Juice Yeah, C++/CLI is only really useful to make an interop layer (which of course makes it a somewhat useful skill for some C# programmers - not as a primary language, though). Although maybe, *maybe* it could also be used to migrate a large codebase of native C++ code to .NET, while slowly rewriting it all under C#.